# Write in the form “if p, then q” in English. To get tenure as a professor, it is sufﬁcient to be world famous.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Write this statement in the form “if p, then q” in English

> To get tenure as a professor, it is sufﬁcient to be world famous.

- By definition of *sufﬁcient*, $p$ sufﬁcient $q$ where  $p$ is Hypothesis and $q$ is Conclusion
- By definition of *conditional Statement*, if $p$ then $q$ where $p$ is Hypothesis and $q$ is conclusion

Let
$p :$ get tenure as a professor;
$q :$ be world famous;

"If you get tenure as a professor, you will be famous."

Why is this wrong?

Comment: Here, fame $\implies $ professorship, not the other way!

Comment: See the post [identifying-necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-in-english-less-clear-cases](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/51194/identifying-necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-in-english-less-clear-cases).

Comment: Maybe a sentence of similar structure will show why it is absurd.

"To end up in hospital, it is sufficient to drink a cup of bleach" in the form you described is obviously not

"If you end up in hospital, then you will drink a cup of bleach,"

it should be

"If you drink a cup of bleach, you will end up in hospital."

Comment: "$A$ is sufficient for $B$" is $A \to B$.

Comment: @Mauro Please tell me is my comment incorrect then

Comment: @samjoe - It is fine :-)

Comment: To gain more knowledge of the topic, you can try visiting [This](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/148441/143377) answer may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back to your first line

> P **sufﬁcient** Q where P is Hypothesis and Q is Conclusion

and compare it to

> it is **sufﬁcient** to be world famous

Thus *being world famous* is sufficient...

Answer (score 0):

If you say

"To get tenure as a professor,it is sufﬁcient to be world famous"

Then this means that if you are world famous, then this is enough to be a professor.

Thus, here, "being famous  = $P$" and "get tenure" = $Q$, and

$$P \implies Q $$.

$P$ is sufficient for $Q$ to be true.